# Does this binary sorting algorithm need to be optimized significantly in memory usage and speed of execution

Tags: python, sorting

I made a binary search algorithm, and I just was wondering if there is a way to increase the performance of memory usage / effective usage of memory and the speed of execution. Specifically, is there a way to quickly insert an item since I know that using the insert method requires shifting the indexes of all the rightward values by 1. This takes time, so is there a faster way to do this, maybe use a different data set that is mutable and index-able? Also, I made this with the intention that the values are all real numbers / floats or integers. Also, am I correct to assume I won't be using much more memory at any given point in the execution due to popping off the values and sorting them into the sorted list. Since A (length of original array) - B (number of values popped off) + B (number of values popped of from the original array that are moved into sorted array) = A.

```
def binary_sort(array: []):
    """ Returns an organized version of the array """
    number = 0
    length = len(array)
    sorted_array = []
    while number < length:
        value = array.pop()
        start = 0
        end = number
        while start < end:
            avg = (start + end) // 2
            v = sorted_array[avg]
            if v <= value:
                start = 1 + avg
            else:
                end = avg
        sorted_array.insert(start, value)
        number += 1
    return sorted_array
```

Comment: That seems to be a sorting algorithm (also what it says in the name of the function), not a search algorithm (what it says in your question and its title). Which one do you want, and if it’s a sort, which sorting algorithm were you trying to implement?

Comment: A binary sorting algorithm, unless it goes by a different name.

Comment: @Ry- it is rather obvious from reading the code that the OP implemented (correctly, it seems) _insertion sort_ using binary search to find the insertion point. And I don't think it might be optimized much. Of course, it is a very academic exercise…

Comment: But is the purpose of this to implement insertion sort, to implement a fast sort, to try to invent a sort [that involves a binary split step]…? Are you doing this to learn, or to solve a problem?

Comment: I am doing this to learn, and solve a linear regression problem (I don't know how to explain how, but it is part of a bigger project that I already finished, but there were a few problems. I mean, I did use an extremely slightly different version to sort a list, that would be 10 ^ 10 numbers long, as I was making it. The list of values was 10 ^ 5, but the length of the list is squared. When I made the list 10 ^ 6, resulting in 10 ^ 12 long list (but I sorted each individual value into the list each time I made a new one). It took a minute which is more than hoped, so I'm trying to improve it.

Comment: Well, for practical sorting, you’ll want to use something more efficient asymptotically than this (which is O(n^2)), e.g. the built-in sort `l = […]; l.sort()`. … but you held a list with 10^12 elements in memory and managed to sort it with this in a minute??  That doesn’t sound right at all.

Comment: How is this O(n ^ 2) I thought it would be O( sum(ceil(log2(i + 1))) for i in range(0, length of completed list) ) since each time I sort a new item into the list (after making it), it takes a max of ceil(log2(1 + length of the list at that time))) number of comaprisons / times i cut the searchable "window" in half or about half.

Comment: Oh, actually it wasnt 10 ^ 12 or 10 ^ 10, it was actually one half of that or 0.5 ^ 10 ^ 10 or 12. I mean from 10 ^ 5 "points" (x, y), i can do (y1 - y2) / (x2 - x1) to create 1/2 * (10 ^ 5)( 10 ^ 5 - 1) values. So yeah, and it took about a minute, maybe 5, but no more than that

Comment: Try the built-in sort, then. (And it’s O(n^2) because of the insertion problem you mentioned in the question. Each insertion takes time proportional to its distance from the end of the list.)

Comment: But how can you make it take less time. I mean if inserting an item does this, how can you get around it since the indexes HAVE to be updated, unless I am unaware of a way to have them not be?

Comment: You make it take less time using an entirely different approach. The built-in sort is [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), for example.

Comment: Oh you are right. I got my numbers mixed up.